# MySQLi - Can't find the user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a connection to my MySQL database through MySQLi by using the following code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "wesley", "", "project_tim" );
```

Now, my error (well, warning) is the following:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'project_tim'

As you can see, there is no user in the error line. What can the problem be? I have the latest version of Xampp, the user is created and both services are running.

Comment: Does your `username` and `password` were correct ? `("wesley", "",)`

Comment: Yes, both username and password are correct (blanked the password out though ;))

Comment: `wesley` user have the permission to access the database?

Comment: Yes, the user has full permission over the database

Comment: Either ways run these command once in your mysql `GRANT ALL ON project_tim.* TO 'wesley'@'localhost';`

Comment: Are you sure that this is the actual source line that's giving the message?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is **wesley** user don't have the permission to access the database.

To provide permission for **wesley** user, run this command in your `MYSQL` console or in `phpMyAdmin`

```
GRANT ALL ON project_tim.* TO 'wesley'@'localhost';
```

And restart your `xampp`